# In MSP, what are the differences between "Status Date" and "Current Date"?

Tags: ms-project, planning

*I googled up a bit about this but could not find a real answer, so here I am!*

In Microsoft Project, you have two things:

- The Current Date (Can be find in Project>Project Information)
- The Status Date (Can be changed directly in the Project tab)

To me Status date should be used to report from a certain date, and the Current date should be used to tell MSP that "today" is a particular day. However, I could not find the list of differences between the use of the 2 dates.

- What are the main differences between the 2 of them?
- How does that each impact the advancement of a task? (For example
  Progress lines...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What are the main differences between the 2 of them?

You want project report for last week (say Friday - 28-Apr-2017), and you are sending the report on Monday (E.g. 01-May-2017)  you set the status date to Friday, 28-Apr-2017. Here status date is 28-April-2017 and the current date is 01-May-2017. The status date is almost never the current date, so you need to set it.

- How does that each impact the advancement of a task? (For example
  Progress lines...)

All the project progress will be based on the date you set. If you have not set the status date, progress will be based on current date.

You can add the status date to Gantt Chart also:

1. On the Gantt Chart, click Format > Gridlines.
2. Under Line to change, pick Status Date, and then select a line style and color.

[image]